# Conditions between the queries

Tags: oracle, plsql, conditional-statements

I have two queries:

```
SELECT Origin_country_id
  FROM item_supp_country_DIM
 WHERE item = I_ITEM
```

and

```
SELECT Origin_country_id
  FROM item_supp_country
 WHERE item = I_ITEM
```

I want to check if first query returns the result - if it doesn't then I want to use my second query to fetch the result.

How do i do this in PLSQL as a conditional thing?

Comment: This looks like a straight forward easy programming task, what is the problem you face when you try? If you need a primer to PL/SQL programming there is a lot around like this one http://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I have not compiled this but more or less it should work.

Basically you can try to read the first table and catch the exception and then try to read the other table. That would be the `PL/SQL` solution.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION read_origin_country (i_item IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
IS
    l_origin_country_id   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT Origin_country_id
          INTO l_origin_country_id
          FROM item_supp_country_DIM
         WHERE item = I_ITEM;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
            SELECT Origin_country_id
              INTO l_origin_country_id
              FROM item_supp_country
             WHERE item = I_ITEM;
    END;

    RETURN l_origin_country_id;
END read_origin_country;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's n alternative without using `plsql`.

You could query both tables at once:

```sql
SELECT 'item_supp_country_DIM' source_table, Origin_country_id
  FROM item_supp_country_DIM
 WHERE item = :I_ITEM
UNION ALL
SELECT 'item_supp_country' source_table, Origin_country_id
  FROM item_supp_country
 WHERE item = :I_ITEM;
```

I don't know your schema or table-sizes. But if `item` has an index, this query should be quick.

Testdata:

```sql
DROP TABLE ITEM_SUPP_COUNTRY_DIM;
DROP TABLE ITEM_SUPP_COUNTRY;

CREATE TABLE ITEM_SUPP_COUNTRY_DIM
(
    ORIGIN_COUNTRY_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ITEM                NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE ITEM_SUPP_COUNTRY
(
    ORIGIN_COUNTRY_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ITEM                NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO ITEM_SUPP_COUNTRY_DIM values(1, 1);
INSERT INTO ITEM_SUPP_COUNTRY_DIM values(2, 2);
INSERT INTO ITEM_SUPP_COUNTRY values(2, 2);
INSERT INTO ITEM_SUPP_COUNTRY values(3, 3);
```

Be aware, that if `I_ITEM := 2` you'll get two result-rows.